# How can I handle the checklist button even after search enable or not for tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, selection

How to handle selection checkList button action even after search enable or not.

When doing search and selected first index and empty search then default first index of element is selected.

How can I handle the checklist elements even after search enable or not.

Below is code what I have done.

```
   var itemListArray =  ["Australia", "Brazil", "Canada","China", "Germany", "India", "Malaysia", "Pakistan", "Russia", "South Africa", "United States of America"]

func configurationTagsCell (cell: LocationTableViewCell,
                            forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){

    if (isSearching){

        let searchTagArray = self.searchListArray[indexPath.row].map{
            (stringName) -> String in
            return String(stringName)
            }.joined(separator: "")
        cell.lbl_LocationName?.text = searchTagArray
        cell.btn_CheckList?.tag = indexPath.row

    }
    else {

        cell.lbl_LocationName?.text = self.itemListArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.btn_CheckList?.tag = indexPath.row

    }

    cell.btn_CheckList?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func checkMarkButtonClicked ( sender: UIButton) {
    print("button presed")

    print_SHLog(sender.tag)

    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false

    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }

}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textfield: UITextField) {

  locationModelView!.isSearching = txt_SearchLocation?.text!.count == 0 ?  false: true
    let filteredStrings = listItemArray.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = item.lowercased().range(of: (textfield.text?.lowercased())!)
        return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
    })
    print(filteredStrings)
    locationModelView.searchListArray = filteredStrings

    if (filteredStrings as NSArray).count > 0
    {
        //Record found
        //MARK:- You can also print the result and can do any kind of work with them
    }
    else{

    }
    self.reloadTableData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach, but the main issue is:

Table view cells are ***reused***. You cannot rely on the state of a cell element, because when you reload the table that cell will no longer be related to the same element in your data.

Basically, you need to create a **data** object that will track the "selected" state of your list. You may want to start like this...

Define a data object:

```
struct MyItem {
    var itemName: String = ""
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

When you load your view controller, create an array of *that* object, and populate it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var itemsArray: [MyItem] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let itemListArray =  ["Australia", "Brazil", "Canada","China", "Germany", "India", "Malaysia", "Pakistan", "Russia", "South Africa", "United States of America"]
        
        itemListArray.forEach { s in
            itemsArray.append(MyItem(itemName: s, isSelected: false))
        }
        
    }

}
```

You now have an array of `MyItem` objects, each with a "name" from your list and each set to "not selected".

When you change the "selected" state, you might do something like this:

```
@objc func checkMarkButtonClicked ( sender: UIButton) {
    print("button presed")
    
    //print_SHLog(sender.tag)

    // toggle the selected state of the button
    sender.isSelected.toggle()

    // update the selected state in your data array
    itemsArray[sender.tag].isSelected = sender.isSelected
}
```

When you display your cells, you'll do something like this:

```
cell.lbl_LocationName?.text = self.itemsArray[indexPath.row].itemName
cell.btn_CheckList?.isSelected = self.itemsArray[indexPath.row].isSelected
cell.btn_CheckList?.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btn_CheckList?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

However, you'll really need to track two data arrays - the "complete" array and the "filtered" array. Of course, the "filtered" array cannot use `indexPath.row` directly, because you need to update the `.isSelected` property of your item in the "complete" array so it will be there when you change the filter.

This may get you on your way, but I'd suggest searching for and reviewing some examples of tracking data changes when using a search field to filter the data, and look for better examples of how to manage buttons in cells.

Comment: I tried your answer its great! would you  please suggest the fillter array its really resolve the issue.